# Bike back wheel came loose a bearing fell out, safe to wheel to repair shop?

Tags: repair

Had my back wheel come loose during a ride, and when I was pushing the bike one of the bearing balls fell out from the axle area I assume.  Is it safe to push the bike to repair shop and how much would it cost to repair?

Comment: There's a disconnect between the title and the actual question.  For clarity: just a ball fell out, not the entire bearing?

Answer (score 7):

We're not really able to give costs sorry.  Your best bet is to telephone the shop and ask "what would a rear hub rebuild cost ?"

---

Your bike shop could charge anything up to two hours of mechanic time, which is in the range of $50 to $250/hour.

The parts cost is minimal - I'd expect them to replace all the bearing balls on both sides, and the balls would be under $10.

The only other costs would be a dab of grease and possibly some rags for cleaning up.

That presumes there is no damage to your cups or cones inside the rear axle, and that the axle itself is undamaged.

---

Another valid option is to do the work yourself.  You'll need a couple of special bike tools, but once you own them then you'll always have them.

- Cone spanner to fit your cones
- Freewheel remover or cassette lockring tool

Normal tools

- Big spanner
- Medium spanner
- Grease and rags

---

You're right, the bike is unsafe to ride in that condition.

If the wheel spins okay, you're probably fine to walk it, but if the wheel hesitates or drags, then pick it up and carry it.

Your other option is to simply take the rear wheel in.  The bike shop does not need the rest of the bike to fix the rear axle in your rear wheel

Comment: I think id have to agree with bertie that something broke like hte axle otherwise it would be weird for the wheel to just dislocate but I dont know jack about bikes.

Comment: @bakalolo fair point - Bearings can drop out if the cone nuts have backed out enough over time, though this is fairly obvious in the wheel's wobbling.

Comment: Also note that the price varies based on the type of back wheels. Some are simple and are just a bearing, others have build in hub gear and brakes

Comment: "The bike shop does not need the rest of the bike" - ideally I'd like to see the frame, to check that the dropouts are undamaged and properly aligned.

Answer (score 6):

Something is probably broken for a ball to escape - my guess is the axle, unless the bearings have collapsed. You probably won't do more harm by wheeling it. Cost will be a new axle and balls or a new wheel, and maybe 20-30 minutes labour (I have no idea what shops charge these days).

Comment: If more bearings fall out while wheeling, you'll be littering your neighbourhood with metal garbage.  So that's not great.

Answer (score 2):

I'm nowhere near as experienced as some of the gurus on here but it sounds like it should be safe to push the bike if just one, or just a small number fell out. Push gently and stop if the wheel "skews".

Ring around a few bike shops in your country to get an idea of costs. If you find that too expensive, consider doing it yourself, it's not difficult.